# ¿Alguien tuvo este problema en SSRS 2016?

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

Les comento que tengo un problema con unos reportes .RDL desarrollados en reporting services, el detalle es el siguiente:

1. Tengo un proyecto de reportes (reporting services), en donde los .rdl usan una librería llamada **WincomTranslator.dll** (librería de la aplicación SAP Contact Center), en la imagen inferior dejo la evidencia de lo comentado:

[image: Imagen 1]

2. Realicé el despliegue de estos reportes en nuestro ambiente de desarrollo donde contamos con la versión Reporting Services 2012, los resultados fueron exitosos, dejo evidencia:

[image: Imagen 2]

3. Cuando intento realizar el mismo despliegue pero en nuestro ambiente de producción en el cual tenemos Reporting Services 2016, se evidencia el siguiente error:

[image: Imagen 3]

El detalle del error es:

**Error 1 Error while loading code module: ‘WicomTranslator, Version=5.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4d18d3cc8a36689’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'WicomTranslator, Version=5.6.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c4d18d3cc8a36689' or one of its dependencies. Failed to grant permission to execute. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131418)**

Ya realicé todos los pasos indicados en la documentación de Microsoft como colocar la librería en determinadas rutas como la carpeta bin del reporte server, la carpeta private del visual studio, etc. Además estoy usando un usuario administrador que tiene todos los privilegios en el servidor de reporting services.

Si alguien tuvo este problema y pudo solucionarlo, agradecería lo pueda compartir.

Gracias de antemano!

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Es por dependencias, revisa que tengas todos tus dll, exe, etc que tienes en tu entorno de desarrollos tengas en tus entrono de producción

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a la comunidad. Es maravilloso que quieras aportar pero evitamos respuestas poco claras. Te invito a hacer [el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que comprendas de que hablo.